# C# dll calling a c++ dll cannot find the dll on windows 10

Tags: c#, c++, dll

i created a c# dll which call a c++ dll.
For this am am doing a simple DLLimport.
This worked fine on all of my Windows 7 machines but now i tried to run it on a Windows 10..
When executing a c# function then i get an error that the called c++ dll cannot be found. (System.DllNotFoundException).

The c# and c++ dll are in the same directory.
I tried to copy both files to the exe file that calls the c# library ->no luck

I tried to copy both files to system32 -> no luck.

Where do i have to copy them so that c# "sees" the c++ dll?
Any way to tell windows where to search?

Thanks for help

Edit:
The C# and C++ dll are developed with "Visual Studio Express 2015".
On the windows 10 system i installed Microsoft Visual C++ 1010/2012/2013/2015 Redistributable x86/x64
The exception is:
An exception occurred inside the call to .NET member 'function_Cs':
System.DllNotFoundException: Die DLL "The_C++_library.dll": Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007E) kann nicht geladen werden.
   bei C#library.C#library.function(Int32 a, Int32 b, Int32& res)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the C++ DLL is in the wrong place; the problem is that it cannot be loaded. Most likely it depends on a version of the Microsoft C++ Runtime Library that is not available by default on Windows 10. You can verify this by checking the status of dependent DLLs via [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). You can either:

- Install the [appropriate version of the runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) OR
- Link your C++ DLL statically

Comment: Thx. I installed the RuntimeLibrarys on Windows 10. But no luck. Version 2015 was already installed before.

Comment: DependencyWalker lists 100s of missing dlls.
Most of them beginn with "API-MS-WIN------" or EXT-MS-WIN-----"

Comment: You need to pay attention to the first level of the tree only. Dependency walker will list dependencies of dependencies, but you only care about what you depend on directly.

Answer (score 0):

After recompiling the sources (without changing anything) the dll can be executed without problems. Strange, but this was the solution.
The not working dll was ~6 month old and worked on other Windows 7 computers.